# How to change the value of an attribute inside the class on the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble changing the value of an attribute that is inside a class, for example:

```
<input class="has-input" value="5" ...>
```

And i have tried to do it like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("has-input")[0].setAttribute("value",1);
```

This would change the value inside the DOM but not on the page and when I try to press the button the real value did not change.

Another way i tried is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("has-input")[0].value=1;
```

This would change the value visually on the page, but once you click the button the real value did not change.

How do I change the real value of that attribute and why does it change in the DOM and page but once I click a button its the old value?

Comment: If you want to get the first element document.querySelector(".has-input").value=1

Comment: This seems to have the same effect as my second example it just changes the value on the site but the real value is still the same once i press a button .

Comment: Do a `console.dir` and check to ensure it's selecting the right element you want to change.

Comment: If you only have one element with that class then you should consider using an id to select and style the element instead. From there you can access it with document.getElementById('id')

Comment: @User404 Could you explain what _"change the value inside the DOM but not on the page"_ means? As you can see in my answer, `1` is displayed inside the input field and when you submit the form, the value is also `1`.

Comment: So .. i am trying to modify the value of a textbox or what you want to call it on an already existing site and nothing seems to be working .. btw is that "okay" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second try is pretty close, but you forgot to select the first element:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('has-input')[0].value = 1;

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.num.value);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="has-input" name="num" value="5">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I actually did have the [0] i just forgot to place it here , sorry i edited it now .

Comment: But if you run my example, it works. If you click on `"Run code snippet", you can see that the input's value is not 5 but 1, as you wanted.